# Multiple IdPs with Sustainsys.Saml2 for the HTTPModule and AspNetCore

Tags: multi-tenant, idp, sustainsys-saml2

In a previous post ([Sustainsys.SAML2 with a multitenant application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776923/sustainsys-saml2-with-a-multitenant-application)) I asked about the process of adding multiple IdPs to my configuration. I have that working but need a little help on implementing this for a multitenant application.

Anders posted this response from Sustainsys:

*The IdentityProviders property on the options is a collection. Just add more IdentityProvider objects to it. To select what Idp to invoke, put an item in the AuthProps with key idp and set the value to the EntityId of the Idp you want to use. It's possible to alter the collection when running.*

I just need a quick code example of Anders' response of "To select what Idp to invoke, put an item in the AuthProps with key idp and set the value to the EntityId of the Idp you want to use." It seems the IdP gets put into the relaystate so when the ACS gets hit, it knows which IdP to use. Anyway, just need some help to complete my understanding of this for use in our multitenant application.

Answer (score 3):

A quick code (.NET Core using Sustainsys.Saml2) example:

```
 var actionParams = new { authenticationType = "Saml2", returnUrl };
 var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
 {
    RedirectUri = _linkGenerator.GetUriByAction(HttpContext, "LoginExternalCallback", null, actionParams)
 };

 properties.Items.Add("idp", new EntityId("someID").Id); // <--- **That's the important line**

 return Challenge(properties, "Saml2"); // <--- Return Challenge from the controller
```

Answer (score 2):

I answered my own question back in the original post. Check out:

[Sustainsys.SAML2 with a multitenant application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776923/sustainsys-saml2-with-a-multitenant-application)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69776923/sustainsys-saml2-with-a-multitenant-application